# Does any blender also do up-down shaking movement?

Tags: equipment

I have a blender. When I try to blend vegetable, I need to hold the blender, shake the blender up and down to make sure the blade cut the vegetable. Does any blender do all for me?

Comment: What kind of blender do you have?

Comment: Blenders are really made to work with liquids (or things that will become liquid), thoroughly blending by creating a vortex. For solids, you'd be better off using a food processor.

Comment: I put water but not too much.

Comment: I have a Magic Bullet Blender

Comment: Upvoted because that is an idea I'd love blender manufacturers to pick up on :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is completely normal while trying to blend solids. It's just that the vortex/space doesn't allow for the large chunks of veg to fall onto the blade. Try a food processor.